Rotating an arrow in flutter with transform.rotate
I have a problem when trying to build an app with an arrow pointing to a destination. I get the bearing for the destination trough Geolocator.bearingBetween and it gives me a bearing in degrees of -46.
Then I try to rotate an arrow with that bearing, but the arrow points to a wrong direction. Here is an example:
Transform.rotate(
            // bearing has a value of -46. So the arrow should point to northwest
            // but the arrow points to north east??
            angle: bearing * (3.1415926535897932 / 180), // Convert degree to radians
            child: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_forward,
              size: 300,
            ),
          ),

What am I doing wrong?
I verified the correct bearing to be the -46 through https://routecompass.mapog.com/ and it points to north west.

The icon arrow_forward normally points towards east, so you have to correct it by subtracting 90 from the degrees.
Transform.rotate(
            angle: (bearing - 90) * (3.1415926535897932 / 180),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_forward,
              size: 300,
            ),

or even better just use arrow_upward instead of arrow_forward.
Transform.rotate(
                angle: bearing * (3.1415926535897932 / 180),
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_upward,
                  size: 300,
                ),


Of course :) how stupid of me. Thanks for pointing that out.

no worries man. Happens to the best of us :)
